# Does the relation between absolute continuity of functions and absolute continuity of measures hold in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure if and only if $\mu\left((-\infty,x]\right)$ is an absolutely continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm wondering if this can be generalized to two dimensions.  Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  My question is, is there some notion of absolute continuity for multivariable functions such that we can say that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure if and only if $\mu\left((-\infty,x]\times(-\infty,y]\right)$ is an absolutely continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

[This paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aff1/ae3f64a409c6060d0e1a8dfa2dd6e66b7f6c.pdf), [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267665797_On_the_notions_of_absolute_continuity_for_functions_of_several_variables), and [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38339114_Notes_on_Absolutely_Continuous_Functions_of_Several_Variables) discuss generalizations of absolute continuity to functions of multiple variables.  Do any of these generalizations yield the notion I want?

This is all an attempt to better understand jointly continuous random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. For a rectangle $R=(a,b]\times (c,d]$ define $F(R)=F(b,d)-F(a,d)-F(b,c)+F(a,c)$. Then, given $\epsilon >0$ three exists $\delta >0$ such that for any finite disjoint collection of $(R_i)$ of rectangles with total area less than $\delta$ we have $\sum F(R_i) <\epsilon$. The converse is also true.

Comment: Do you have a reference or a proof for that result?

Comment: You can prove this exactly the way you prove it one dimension. Note that $\mu <<\nu$ implies that $\mu(E) \to 0$ as $\nu (E) \to 0$.